# From which level should I start learning English Language?

Tags: learning

I was learning English Language from Grade 1 until my graduation from the university. But I can't talk, write and listen good. I don't know my English Language Level. How to determine the Level? When I answer some question test, I got intermediate, advantage but sometime i got basic level. How to define the level of my English Language?

Comment: You want to enroll in an English language learning program, but don't know which level to pick?

Comment: yes! I feel What level should i enroll ?@CopperKettle

Comment: Interesting. It seems that it's not only two of my teachers that have the same problem: Teach the best grammar, while making the strangest, and sometimes funniest ;) , of sentences.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem some years ago and figured out that there were two main goals (for me):

- speaking fluently
- speaking correctly (grammar)

My teacher told me that usually speaking fluently is more important because natives can see over your little mistakes. "But I can't talk, write <strike>and</strike> **or** listen <strike>good</strike>**very well**(?)", anyway your message is clear.

She also told me that with a lot of talking you improve your grammar **but not the other way round**.

So what I did was hitting up some native guys online (video games) and I started voice chatting with them for more than 2 years now. Doing so, I (mercilessly) found out about what I still had to learn. Looking for the right course was easy after this :)